# Unable to deserialize polymorphic dictionary json due to KnownType "__type" issue

Tags: c#, .net, types, polymorphism, datacontractjsonserializer

I have created a dictionary with polymorphic values in which I have saved a class object. I have successfully serialized the JSON. But I am unable to deserialize it. It gives below error:

> Element ':Value' contains data of the ':Sale' data contract. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this contract.

If replace the JSON property `"__type"` with `"type"` then it works but is unable to recover correct object type. Before serialization it contains an object of my class type but after deserialization it contains a `system.object` instead.

My code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dict.Add("employee","john");
        dict.Add("sale",new Sale(9,5243));
        dict.Add("restaurant",new Restaurant("Cheese Cake Factory", "New York"));
        //  Console.Write(dict["sale"]);

        //Code for JSON
        DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>));  
        MemoryStream msObj = new MemoryStream();  
        js.WriteObject(msObj, dict);  
        msObj.Position = 0;  
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(msObj);  
        string json = sr.ReadToEnd();  
        sr.Close();  
        msObj.Close();

        // Decode the thing
        Console.Write(json);

        Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>));
            result = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as Dictionary<string, object>;
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Sale))]
public class Sale 
{
    [DataMember(Name = "SaleId")]
    public int SaleId {get; set;}
    [DataMember(Name = "Total")]
    public int Total{ get; set;}

    public Sale(int saleid, int total)
    {
        SaleId = saleid;
        Total = total;
    }

    public int getTotal()
    {
        return  Total;
    }
}

[DataContract(Name = "Restaurant", Namespace="")]
[KnownType(typeof(Restaurant))]
public class Restaurant
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Name {get; set;}
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string City{get; set;}

    public Restaurant(string name, string city)
    {
        Name = name;
        City = city;
    }
}
```

Fiddle link : https://dotnetfiddle.net/CfQxxV

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that you're putting `[KnownType(typeof(...))]` above `sale` and `Restaurant`.

The reason for using KnownType is for conversion between 1 and the other object. So the deserializer doesn't know that `Sale` is a KnownType of `Object`. so it can't Convert Object to Sale.

This would only work if all the items in your dictionary share a common parent object like this:

```
    [KnownType(typeof(Sale))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Restaurant))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Employee))]
    [DataContract]
    public class SomeObject {

    }

    [DataContract(Name = "Sale", Namespace="")]
    public class Sale : SomeObject
    {
       //methods + properties + variables
    }

    [DataContract(Name = "Restaurant", Namespace="")]
    public class Restaurant : SomeObject
    {
        //methods + properties + variables   
    }

    [DataContract(Name = "Employee", Namespace="")]
    public class Employee: SomeObject
    {
        //methods + properties + variables   
    }
```

and then use the dictionary as

```
Dictionary<string, SomeObject> dict = new Dictionary<string, SomeObject>();
```

Comment: Thanks for quick solution. It'working fine. I have updated the fiddle. But I unable to add non object. So have you any idea? so that I can also add below.

 dict.Add("employee","john");

Comment: It would also need to be an object that extends `SomeObject`, I slightly edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to serialize a root object `Dictionary<string, object>` with polymorphic members.  The data contract serializers use a *whitelisting* approach to polymorphism: all polymorphic subtypes encountered during serialization must have been *previously declared* via the [known type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-known-types) mechanism before an instance of that subtype is encountered in the serialization graph.

So, how can that be done using your data model?   There are several approaches:

1. Add [`[KnownType(typeof(TDerivedObject))]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute?view=netframework-4.8) directly to a base type that is statically declared as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58836078/3744182) by [Joost K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8796313/joost-k).

   This can't work here because the base type is `object`, which you cannot modify.
2. Add `[KnownType(typeof(TDerivedObject))]` to some *parent object* in the serialization graph.

   This looks problematic because your root object type is `Dictionary<string, object>`, however you could subclass the dictionary to get your desired result:

   ```
   [KnownType(typeof(Sale))]
   [KnownType(typeof(Restaurant))]
   public class ObjectDictionary : Dictionary<string, object>
   {
   }
   ```

   Then construct and serialize your dictionary using this subclass:

   ```
   var dict = new ObjectDictionary()
   {
       { "employee","john" },
       {"sale",new Sale(9,5243) },
       {"restaurant",new Restaurant("Cheese Cake Factory", "New York")},
   };

   DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObjectDictionary));
   ```

   Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M6iHP8).
3. Configure additional known types in runtime by [constructing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_Serialization_Json_DataContractJsonSerializer__ctor_System_Type_System_Runtime_Serialization_Json_DataContractJsonSerializerSettings_) a serializer using a [`DataContractJsonSerializerSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings?view=netframework-4.8) with known types specified in [`DataContractJsonSerializerSettings.KnownTypes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.knowntypes?view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_Serialization_Json_DataContractJsonSerializerSettings_KnownTypes):

   ```
   var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings
   {
       KnownTypes = new [] { typeof(Sale), typeof(Restaurant) },
   };
   DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), settings);
   ```

   Be sure to configure the serializer in the same way for both serialization and deserialization.

   Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OYh7ly).

   (For XML use [`DataContractSerializerSettings.KnownTypes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializersettings.knowntypes?view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_Serialization_DataContractSerializerSettings_KnownTypes).)
4. Specify additional known types via configuration file as shown in *[Additional Ways to Add Known Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-known-types#additional-ways-to-add-known-types)*.
5. You are serializing directly, but if you were serializing via WCF you could add [`ServiceKnownTypeAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute?view=netframework-4.8) to your service contract.

It is never necessary to add `[KnownType(typeof(TClass))]` to `TClass` itself, so you can remove such attributes from `Restaurant` and `Sale`:

```
[DataContract]
//[KnownType(typeof(Sale))] Remove this
public class Sale 
{
    // Remainder unchanged
}
```

For more, see *[All About KnownTypes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sowmy/2006/06/06/all-about-knowntypes/)* by [Sowmy Srinivasan](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sowmy/).